# Opening another window through pushbutton in GUI in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt

I am new to Python and to PyQt. I have designed GUIs in MATLAB so its been a frustrating new experience. Right now, I have a main window and I want to open another login window on button push. What I have not decided is whether it should return the value of login to the parent window or another window. But either way I need to be able to open the login window through the pushbutton. I have created 2 files declaring the GUI one as a mainwindow and another as Dialog (does not seem like it is inheriting from QDialog though). The other 2 py files are classed calling the UIs separately and work fine. Each have their functions. I am pasting the main.py (mainwindow init and onOpen function code) along with logindialog.py init function code. Kindly help or else I will have to go back to Matlab where I can do this quite easily.`

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from LoginDialog import LoginDialog
import UI_MSLDB_Main
from UI_LoginDialog import Ui_LoginDialog
#import Helper
#import Auth
#import TestFeature01

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, UI_MSLDB_Main.Ui_MSLDatabase):
    def _init_(self, parent = None):
         QtWidgets.QMainWindow._init_(self)
         self.setupUi(self)
         self.child = LoginDialog(self)
         self.child.setupUi(QtWidgets.QDialog())
#         self.createConnections()
         self.pushButton_OpenPrimarylist.clicked.connect(self.onOpen)

    def onOpen(self):
#        window = QtWidgets.QDialog
#        self.child = LoginDialog(window, Ui_LoginDialog)
#         self.child.show()
#        exec('LoginDialog.py')
        self.child.show

#        self.actionStudy.triggered.connect()


 if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#    LoginDialog(QDialog, Ui_LoginDialog)

#    loginDialog = LoginDialog(QDialog, UI_LoginDialog)
#    username = loginDialog.username
#    password =loginDialog.password
#    Helper.dbConnect(username,password)

#    isAuth = False
#    result = -1
#    while not isAuth:
#        result = loginDialog.exec()
#        if result == LoginDialog.Success or result == LoginDialog.Rejected:
#            isAuth = True
#        else:
#            isAuth = False
    result = 1 
    if result == 1:#LoginDialog.Success:
        MSLDatabase = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = UI_MSLDB_Main.Ui_MSLDatabase()
        ui.setupUi(MSLDatabase)
        MSLDatabase.show()

    #        w.show()
        app.exec_()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

There were multiple things I tried not knowing which would work. The commented codes are the ones I have tried and failed. LoginDialog class is below.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
import Auth
import Helper
from UI_LoginDialog import Ui_LoginDialog

class LoginDialog(QDialog, Ui_LoginDialog):
    Success, Failed, Rejected, username, password = range(0,5)

    def _init_(self):
        QDialog._init_(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL 
            (_fromUtf8("accepted()")),self.onAccept)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, 
            QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("rejected()")),
                           self.onReject)
```

Comment: `self.child.show` or `self.child.show()`, is typo?

Comment: That was a typo. Modified but it still does not work.

Comment: I did both of those as you had suggested and it still does not work.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AjxkmaEIjdC-l0VjvYV3hUG8PN9u

Comment: These are the files that I am working with currently.

Comment: the init method must have two underscores before and after, ie it changes: `__init__`.  Also in the main you must create an object of the type Main: `if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    if result == 1:#LoginDialog.Success:
        MSLDatabase = Main()
        MSLDatabase.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())`

Comment: Change to:  `class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, UI_MSLDB_Main.Ui_MSLDatabase):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
         QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)`

Comment: Ok so nothing is working. I figured out the pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.onOpen) is not calling onOpen(self) function. I do not know why. the only thing I know is in Spyder when I place a dot after clicked connect function does not open up as an option. Am I missing something?

Comment: Send me your code with the corrections that I said, I see that the errors that I mention are in other files, I'm lazy to correct all, run it from a terminal and you will see the errors, the IDEs sometimes do not handle the errors correctly.

Comment: The updated files are here: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AjxkmaEIjdC-l0VjvYV3hUG8PN9u

Comment: Also, I tried to modify my main UI file and added the onOpen function there with a simple text change return. It worked but the same did not work in main.py.

Comment: try with this code: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/610b60ffc1721b6788db793408385e3920171017174628/688359

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked. So, kindly guide as to what was wrong with the code. Why would this method work by creating a separate attribute instead of using .child? Even if we were to not include the child, the onOpen function should have changed the text why was it not doing that?Thanks again.

Comment: Look at the `if __name__ == '__main__':` function, you are adding the Qt Designer layout

Comment: Thanks again. So, because I was essentially declaring my setupUI function again, it was not passing the onOpen function.

Comment: You created a window where you connected the button, but then you added a new design and the button you observed is different than the one you connected initially.